# mongodump'ing a 32-bit Older Version of MongoDB and mongorestore'ing It To 64-bit Updated Version

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I have a production server that happens to be using a single instance of an older 32-bit version of MongoDB (2.0.0).  I wanted to check a couple things before I got down and dirty with moving this data over to a separate server.

1. Will there be any conflicts doing a mongodump on a 32-bit install and a mongorestore to a 64-bit installation?
2. Is there any problems moving a 2.0 database dump to a 2.2.x installation?

I've read you are unable to do a mongodump of a 2.2 and correctly mongorestore to a 2.0, but I'm just doing a version upgrade.  I've also read you can do replica sets between 32-bit and 64-bit versions of MongoDB, so I'm hoping this transition will work fine.

Just wanted to check, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will there be any conflicts doing a mongodump on a 32-bit install and
>   a mongorestore to a 64-bit installation?

No, this will be fine, no problems - the BSON format will not be changed because of architecture

> Is there any problems moving a 2.0 database dump to a 2.2.x
>   installation?

No problems here either, in fact you can just copy the data files directly if you wish (as long as the source DB is shut down at the time).  That will in fact be faster because you won't have to rebuild indexes.

Comment: Thank you good sir, I appreciate it.  I'm not really a network admin, I just know we were about to run into issues with the database running out of room.  :O